# gradle application plugin and missing classpath for kafka storm Spout

Tags: java, gradle, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm trying to use the application plugin to run a Kafka-Storm topology.
This is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "Library"

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13',
            'org.apache.storm:storm-core:0.10.0',
            'org.apache.storm:storm-kafka:0.10.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

When I launch `./gradlew run` I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/api/OffsetRequest
    at storm.kafka.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.java:43)
    at storm.kafka.SpoutConfig.<init>(SpoutConfig.java:40)
    at Library.main(Library.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.api.OffsetRequest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

Have I configured the `application` plugin in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This failure suggests that a dependency is missing.

Perhaps adding `compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.2.2'` to your `dependencies {}` block will help you make progress.

Note that the exact kafka may be different depending on the version of Kafka etc you are running.

If you want to exclude transitive dependencies, you can change the `compile...` statement above to:

```
dependencies {
  compile('org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.2.2') {
     // transitive = false // No transitive dependencies
     exclude group: 'foo'  // Exclude specific dependencies
  }
}
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

Comment: That was it. Do you think is it possibile to import a subset of kafka dependencies instead of the complete distribution?

Comment: Yep, there are 2 ways to do this. I'm updating my answer with suggestions

Comment: Thanks, I actually knew that, I hope there was a package specifically for kafka+storm. Tnx!